# Inconsistency between UIView and UITableView in background image

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uiview, background-image

I have a tab bar controller containing two tabs: UIView and UITableView controllers.

I'm trying to have the same background image in them, but the problem is that the image is resized in the UITableView.

[Here](http://i45.tinypic.com/1o64bb.jpg) you can see the difference.

In order to add background image I used this code in the UIView:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
[[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.jpg"] drawInRect:self.view.bounds];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:image];
```

and this for UITableView:

```
UIImageView *tempImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:
[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.jpg"]];
[tempImageView setFrame:self.tableView.frame];
self.tableView.backgroundView = tempImageView;
```

To check the view frame size I used

```
NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGSize(self.view.frame.size));
```

and used this one for table view

```
NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.tableView.frame));
```

the result is the same ({320, 460})

I even tried to add the UIView background image in XCode IB but had no luck.

The image is jpg with size 640 X 1136. I also tried a png file and had no luck.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `colorWithPatternImage:` for both the cases.

`self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:YOUR IMAGE"]];`

Comment: This works but it uses massive memory, way more than you would expect. Please refer this for more details. http://www.cocoaintheshell.com/2011/01/colorwithpatternimage-memory-usage/

Answer (score 1):

What I did using Pranav's answer is, in the UITableView I used:

```
UIView* backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.bounds.size.width, self.tableView.bounds.size.height)];
[backgroundView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.jpg"]]]; 
[self.tableView setBackgroundView:backgroundView];
```

and in the UIView I just used:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.jpg"]];
```